# Javascript syntax: variable declaration with "<<" or ">>"

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, word-cloud

I had a look at [Jason Davies's Word Cloud source on Github](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) 
and within the [index.js](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/index.js) there are some variables that are declared like this:

```
cw = 1 << 11 >> 5,
ch = 1 << 11;
```

I noticed this pattern: 
value before "<<" multiplies the value after "<<";
value after "<<" is a 2 to the power of the value specified; 
value after ">>" (following "<<") divides that number before (which is also 2 two the power of the value);

I was curious:

1. in general what are the uses for this type of declaration and where does it come from
2. how does it add value to the code in the rest of the Jason Davies' layout?

Comment: I think he's just being silly. He's declaring `cw` as `1 << 11 >> 5`, but then every place in that file that actually uses `cw` has `(cw << 5)`. (At first I thought maybe it was a weird attempt to self-document that those variables are to be used for bit-masking purposes, but in fact they're not used for that.)

Comment: *"how does it add value to the code in the rest of the Jason Davies' layout?"*. It doesn't, in fact it just makes it run slightly slower (compared to just doing `cw = 64`). Looks like the programmer was just bored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift)

Basically, `<<` and `>>` do bit-wise shifts. If you do `a << b`, it will represent `a` as a number in base 2 (0s and 1s) and shift all the digits to the left by `b` positions. This is mathematically equivalent to

```
a * 2^b
```

The `>>` is the same principle, but it shifts to the right. It's almost analogous to a division by a factor of 2, but there's a special case when the intial number is odd: it floors the result.

```
⌊(a / 2^b)⌋
```

If you have `1 << 11 >> 5`, the left and right shifts cancel each other, we end up in reality with

```
1 << 6 === 64 === 1 * 2^6
```

Comment: Well yes, that's what the `<<` and `>>` operators do, but the question asks what the point of using them in those declarations is. In the JS file in question, every time the variable `cw` is used it appears as `(cw << 5)`.

Comment: I can't confirm if it's the case in JS, but doing bit-wise operations is usually more performant compared to doing multiplications.

Let's say you know you want to multiply by some multiple 2, it would be better to left shift rather than doing the multiplication. You see that more often in more down-to-the-metal programming though.

Comment: Sure. But in a *declaration* it would be more performant to say `cw = 64`. Or `cw = 2048` and then *not* say `(cw << 5)` every time the variable is used. The original code is just weird. (By the way, if you were keen to confirm performance you could do some tests at https://jsperf.com/, except they seem to be down for upgrades at the moment.)

Comment: Indeed; as you said, he was probably just being silly. But, using `<< >>` can have real value.